# that + adjective + a/an + noun

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is it possible to omit "of" in such sentences.

> 1- It wasn’t that nice ***of*** a host family after all.
>
> 2-  It wasn't that nice a host family after all.

Comment: I like it a bit better with *of*.

Comment: Thank you. But it is possible to omit I think? I have seen such sentences from native speakers: "It's not that bad a situation."

Comment: It sounds a little funny to my ear in your sample sentence, so I tried some other examples: *It wasn't that bad a deal after all, it wasn't that complicated a recipe after all.*  Okay, you convinced me, leaving out "of" doesn't seem to change the meaning.  Hopefully someone else will weigh in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works either way.  When writing, I would prefer using "of" for clarity, but I might say it without the "of".

"not that nice a hotel", "not that great a cook", "not that good a hockey player" are some other examples I found on google.